How to hide API key when sharing on Github
I am doing a project with Python. I don't want the api keys to be visible when I share my code on Github, but if they are not visible, I can't deploy with streamlit. What should I do?
For now, I am waiting in this way. I am waiting for your help.
image

It's common to put API keys in an environment file that you edit by hand, rather than include in the distribution.

Use Github secrets

Have you read secrets management in streamlit?

Okay, I fixed the problem, thank you everyone

Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
